# Android Studio - Design view failing to resolve module dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio

I have three modules:

[image]

All of my resources, styles, strings, values, colours are all in the **resource-module**

All of the xml layouts in the main application module **App** can access them and Android Studios Design View is working fine.

However for the **home-module** the Design View looks like this:
[image]

Both **build.gradle** contain the following:

> compile project(path: ':resource-module')

The only difference I can see between the modules is the **App** contains:

> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

and the **home-module** contains:

> apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

The Application complies fine and is picking up the correct resources when it runs.

Problem is just the Android Studios Design View is not working.
Does anyone know if theres a way to help it find the **resource-module** so that it can access the dependancies?

Comment: I'm not sure. (By looking at your screenshot) If you're using `?attr/colorPrimary` and `?attr/textEditSuggestionItemLayout` in your layout remove it and try to clean and build. This should work. or Invalidate cache and restart Android Studio.

Comment: I can remove them all and the Design View starts working. However that doesn't solve the problem, I want to be able to reference the resources from the resource module.The Application module is able to do this.

Comment: did you try _Invalidate Cache and Restart_ without removing those lines? This should work.

Comment: Yes and just did it again for good measure but no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most the issue is most probably not related to module-dependencies.

You need to check that the inheritance of the theme used by the home-module tracks back to an AppCompat theme.

For instance, it is very usual for people to ***wrongly*** define:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Note that `AppTheme.NoActionBar` is not defining its parent, therefore, the theme is not a child of AppCompat. You would need to define its parent:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

This will help the IDE identify the base theme to show you some nice graphs.